# HTML margins squishing when viewed on Mobile device

Tags: html, css

I tried to use a couple of posts that were here for resizing for mobile devices but i can't seem to get it working. The margins keep pushing all the elements together when you view the site on a mobile device

/* TEXT FORMATTING */

```
    .introPar1 {
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-left: 400px;
            margin-right: 400px;
            font-size: 30px;
    }

    .introPar1 h1 {
            text-align: center;
    }

    .contacts {
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-left: 400px;
            margin-right: 400px;
            font-size: 30px;

     }
```

/* MOBILE FORMATTING */

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    introPar1 {
        margin-right: 20px;
        `enter code here`margin-left: 20px;
         }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    body {
        margin-right: 5vw;
        margin-left: 5vw;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        margin-right: 2vw;
        margin-left: 2vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: margins squishing ? what does that mean ? also share here the html and replicate the problem. do not share external sites

Comment: If you open the webite on a mobile device all of the elements get pushed either in the middle or to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this page on mobile devices like this
[image]

You need to change like this

[image]

then increase the nav bar width

(I tried width: 1520px; for Nav beacuse that is the background image size you were used)

Comment: What is that called when the margins format like that on a mobile device

Comment: you meant how to refer the issue mentioned in screenshot 1? @user3765758

Comment: Yes, that was probably what was handicapping me when i was trying to google because i didn't even know what it was called.

Comment: There is no specific text to search. We can't search like that. Just we need to look in to the design, Why this element taking this much of height/width like that, so we can found what is the root cause
Did you try my answer? is that works for you

Comment: No I did not try it yet (sorry for the late reply the overnight shift is screwing with my head) I just now got to putting in the viewport tags and stuff. Where did you put the 1520px?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of problems with your code. But the problem with the menu is because `li` is not taking the height of `a`. So the list items will stack one under another, and will li under li. Li being smaller than a.

Use `display:block` on `a`.

Also, I copied the code from your site, so it will be here if someone else comes looking for this answer. Tried to clean it up a bit but you have some styles that i don't understand, like `.introPar1 { margin-left:400px;margin-right:400px}`

Anyway, see code below

```css
body img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* TOP NAVIGATION */

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* NAV HOVER */

nav a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
  color: white;
  transition: .3s;
}


/* BANNER */

.banner {
  text-align: center;
}

.banner img {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: #87CEEB;
}


/* BODY ELEMENTS */

.home {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.temp {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* BACKGROUND */

.bgimage img {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
}


/* TEXT FORMATTING */

.introPar1 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.introPar1 h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.contacts {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* MOBILE FORMATTING */

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  introPar1 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 2vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimage">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1000">
</div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Crafts LLC</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="banner"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>


<div class="Intro">
  <article class="introPar1">
    <h1><b><u>CRAFTS LLC</u></b></h1>
    <br> Here at CRAFTS LLC, we offer you our 45 years of expertise of
    <br> home repair advisory and remodeling services
    <br>
    <br> We are also here to help you with your estimation service needs
    <br> and contractor referral services
    <br>
    <br> With CRAFTS LLC, you get both service and quality excellence.
    <br> You need to look no further for your home repair and remodeling needs/solutions
    <br>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="contacts">
  <p>Email to: craftsllc1@gmail.com or Call:813 347 7458</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i'm just now getting back to this. I used the margins to push the stuff in the middle how i wanted it to show up but that seems to be what is breaking when its on a a mobile device :/

Comment: @user3765758 well you need to use responsive units like `vh` or `vw` or maybe percentages `%` . Do not use pixels. For example if you use `margin-left:400px` , that might work on very big screens, but on laptop/tablet/mobile, those are a lot of pixels :) so use `margin-left:5vw` and `margin-right:5vw` . or use `width:80%;margin:0 10%` . There are a number of ways to center a div, but `margin-left:400px` is not one of them

Comment: So the margin is ok just not with px

Comment: Mihai, is there another way to center the whole div without margins?

Comment: try `margin:0 auto` . there are a number of ways to center the div

Comment: this is what happens when I take those margins off. It spreads the entire grey background end to end http://imgur.com/HXMs7ff

Comment: Mihai, when I tried to use margin:0 auto it stretched the paragraph across the entire page horizontally